# algorithm to keep sorted order of changing array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have 20-items array which contains decimal numbers. They are unsorted. On every iteration only several items of the array change (~1-3 items of 20-items array). After each iteration I need to have the same array but "sorted".

I shouldn't modify original array, instead I need to maintain "parallel" structure which represents the same array, but sorted. It's allowed to use pointers.

I do care about latency so I need straighforward solution! Obviously I can use double-linked list to "remember" sort order, but I will spent K*O(n) (with pretty big K) to update this list what sound a little bit to expensive. I'm looking for something better that two-linked list.

i will implement this on c# if this matter

Comment: Your original array however is modified to at least include the added items right?  I assume each new item is added to the bottom of your original array?

Comment: If the application remembers which elements actually changed, you could move these "hot" items to there appropiate places, using insertion sort (memmove) or a "partial" bubblesort like method. If you insist on linked lists: finding the odd ones takes one sequential pass, sorting it is 3log(3), and remerging it is O(N) again. BTW: 20 is small. Maybe you don't *need* to keep it sorted.

Comment: @user1161318 items are not added. array also has constant size of 20. items only modify

Comment: @wildplasser i need to iterate array in sorted order pretty often

Comment: An other way would be to use a parallel index- or offset- (or even pointer-) array, which is modified, keeping the original array unaltered. This could be useful if the array elements are big or vary in size.

Comment: i have to keep original array unaltered because I need to access it by index to update elements on each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you keep track of the 1-3 changed elements, it can be done pretty efficiently **using a single step of merge-sort**, and an extra iteration over the array

1. Collect all elements into two arrays `changed` and `notChanged`<sup>1</sup> - in order.
2. sort `changed` (for 1-3 elements, it should be fairly easy and quick).
3. use `merge(changed,notChanged)` to get a sorted array

The complexity is `O(n)` with pretty good constants I believe, since `merge()` is done in a single iteration and so does the collection phase. Also, since we are still using arrays, this approach should be pretty cache efficient.

---

(1) Note that `notChanged` is sorted, because the not changed elements are sorted between themselves!

Comment: sorry i don't understand that. i already have one original unsorted array where 1-3 elements change on each "iteration". how many extra arrays do I need? what is `merge`?

Answer (score 0):

Just use two structures: This is straightforward, robust since you use existing well working collectsions, and cheap by implementation costs:

Use two collections:

One unsorted: e.g in java ArrayList whch is a dynamic growing array
One sorted: use whatever you want.
Both "collections" as usual, point to the content object.

To make things threadsafe in case of multi threading:

encapsulate both collections in one class, where you syncronize all access,
such that reading and writing to both collections is ever synced.